# How to use gdal ogr2ogr to subset features by attributes stored in a csv?

Tags: gdal, ogr2ogr

I have a very large GDB file with about 5000 polygon features, several GB in size, that takes a very long time to load into memory. I want to reduce the number of polygons to something I can work with more easily. The polygons have an attribute `SCINAME` and I have a .csv file with a list of a few hundred `SCINAME`s. How can I construct a call to `ogr2ogr` to create a new .shp file that is a subset of the original GDB only including the polygons that have a `SCINAME` found in my .csv file? Or is there a better command-line way to do it?

**Edit**: I made a shell script with a while loop to do this, but it is running extremely slowly. Please take a look and see why it might be so slow.

```
while read line; do
    echo $line
    ogr2ogr -append -where SCINAME="'$line'" -f "ESRI Shapefile" ./output input.gdb/ "Feature_class_name"
done < scinames.txt
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I solved this by creating a text file with all the names separated by commas, then got what I wanted with a single `ogr2ogr` call.

The contents of the text file (single line) look like:

```
'Abeillia abeillei','Acanthidops bairdi','Acanthis flammea',
'Accipiter bicolor','Accipiter cooperii' ... and so on
```

The subset is created with this code:

```
scinamestring=$(cat scinames.txt)
ogr2ogr -f "ESRI Shapefile" -sql "SELECT * FROM Feature_class_name WHERE SCINAME IN ($scinamestring)" ./output input.gdb/
```

Comment: Hi I am doing the same thing. But I am a bit confused - what does "Feature_class_name" mean here? I am getting this error `ERROR 1: SELECT from table Feature_class_name failed, no such table/featureclass`

Comment: I think maybe the `Feature_class_name` was something specific to the .gdb file I was working with... you might need to replace it with a different name? Not sure as it's been a while.

Comment: Okay. It's the name of the selected layer. Just one more question.  I am getting an error with `./output`. I was wondering how does the dynamic naming of the output shapefiles works without any dynamic variable in this argument?

Comment: I guess try replacing `output` with the desired name of your shapefile, with shp extension?

Comment: @rm167 I am assuming this answered the question? https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/423552/how-to-dynamically-name-the-output-file-in-ogr2ogr