# How to dynamically name the output file in ogr2ogr

Tags: gdal, sql, ogr2ogr, file-geodatabase

I am using ogr2ogr to convert my huge geodatabase file (`mygdb.gdb`) into multiple shapefiles using one of the attributes (`myattr`). I have 100s of unique values for this attributes, so I am gonna do this on a loop.  Based on the answer [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/287264/how-to-use-gdal-ogr2ogr-to-subset-features-by-attributes-stored-in-a-csv), I created a list of these values in a text file (`myattr.txt`). I am going to do the following

```
mystring=$(cat myattr.txt)

ogr2ogr -f "ESRI Shapefile" -sql "SELECT * FROM my_layer WHERE "myattr" IN ($mystring)" myoutput mygdb.gdb
```

My question is how to dynamically name the output shape files i.e. what to write for `myoutput`? The linked answer suggets `/output`. I was wondering how does the dynamic naming of the output shapefiles works without any dynamic variable in this argument?

Comment: you should use a for loop, so you get one name at a time and use it for each shapefile.

Comment: Could you please provide an example? I haven't used a for loop in bash before. Thanks.

Comment: you will find a bunch of different examples in Google, try some of them and check if they work for you. Post your results and we will give some advices if necessary.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you have a textfile `myattr.txt` with all your uniques values (one line per value).

You have to iterate over each line and create a Shapefile for each unique value :

```bsh
cat myattr.txt | while read line 
do
   echo "$line"
   ogr2ogr -f "ESRI Shapefile" -sql "SELECT * FROM my_layer WHERE "myattr" ='$line'" $line.shp mygdb.gdb
done
```