# ogr2ogr's sql works with small number of inputs to filter geopackage, but doesn't with large input

Tags: gdal, sql, ogr, geopackage

I have a `.txt` file that has all the features I want to select. It looks like this in the small version:

```
('100mN25991E46719','100mN25993E46718','100mN26000E46712','100mN26002E46691','100mN26003E46700','100mN26004E46705','100mN26004E46710','100mN26007E46705','100mN26008E46706','100mN26008E46707')
```

Here is the large (18.8 MB) version with all features:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1t5H4SpqyEZ6SsCOhCXMh-zoYSW4Nr467/view?usp=sharing

I want to subset this large! (2.8 GB) geopackage: https://data.statistik.gv.at/data/OGDEXT_RASTER_1_STATISTIK_AUSTRIA_LAEA_GPKG.zip

I found this StackOverflow answer: [How to use gdal ogr2ogr to subset features by attributes stored in a csv?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/287264/how-to-use-gdal-ogr2ogr-to-subset-features-by-attributes-stored-in-a-csv)
which does exactly what I want to do.

Yet, when I call:

```
cells_with_data=$(cat cells_with_data.txt)

ogr2ogr -sql "Select * from l000100 where cellcode IN $cells_with_data" ./output.gpkg STATISTIK_AUSTRIA_RASTER_LAEA_3035.gpkg
```

It works with the small input from above, however, when I use the 18.8 MB textfile with all all the codes I want to keep in the output, it throws this error:

```
zsh: argument list too long: ogr2ogr
```

Which first does not seem to me to be related to the size of the input, but for some reason it works with the smaller one...

Any idea what I might be doing wrong here?

Comment: Try the [`@filename` syntax](https://gdal.org/programs/ogr2ogr.html), but you're probably still going to run into a SQL limit rather than the commandline limit you hit.

Comment: Note that the problem isn't coming from ogr2ogr. Its coming from zsh, which appears to object to you passing 18.8 MB of command line arguments.

Comment: got it! Thanks a lot:)

Comment: Please write that as an answer.